# pool.map() doesn't recognize variable declared in main thread

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

So let's say for example:

```
import multiprocessing

def process(lines):
    print(something)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    something = 'something'
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(10)
    with open(r'C:\Users\a\testfiles\test.txt') as lines:
            pool.map(process, lines)
```

I get a NameError: name 'something' is not defined.

Anyone know why this is happening, and know a fix?

Comment: It's a scoping issue. How are you going to `print(something)` inside a method when it's not even defined?

Comment: something is defined in the main thread under the 'if' statement. If I called process(lines) under the if statement directly, it would print out 'something'. So why doesn't it do it if not called directly?

Comment: Well, it's a little weird to use an argument in a method then not pass that argument to something inside the method. What you have done is basically tell your `process` method to only print whatever the variable `something` is assigned to. So, `lines` as an argument means nothing. That might be your issue.

Comment: Lines as an argument gives pool.map something to iterate over. I could've done the same thing with iterating over a list, other than the lines of a text file, but that is irrelevant in this case. The problem is that the "something" variable isn't shared between the main line and the threads. If I define "something" within the process function it works just fine. The question is how can i share the "something" variable with the threads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`multiprocessing.Pool` is not a thread-pool, it's a process-pool. Windows doesn't support forking hence you would have to pass `something` explicitly to a new process.

If you want to use a thread-pool, use `from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool` instead.

Comment: Thanks! The problem came from my fundamental lack of knowledge how multiprocessing works. TIL.